# Run after block after specific test in Rspec

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, hook

Is there a way I can run the after/before block after/before a specific test using labels?

I have 3 `it` blocks

```
describe "describe" do

  it "test1" do
  end

  it "test2" do
  end

  after(<<what goes here??>>) do
  end

end
```

How do I run the after block only after test2? Is that possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `context`s to do this. Something like:

```
describe "describe" do
  context 'logged in' do
    before(:each) do
      # thing that happens in logged in context
    end

    after(:each) do
      # thing that happens in logged in context
    end

    it "test1" do
    end
  end

  context 'not logged in' do
    # No before/after hooks here. Just beautiful test isolation

    it "test2" do
    end
  end
end
```

Having if/else conditions in before/after blocks is a code smell. Don't do it that way. It'll only make your tests brittle, error prone, and hard to change.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is just use a `context`. For your example:

```
describe "AutomateFr33k's fr33ky tests" do

  it "runs test1" do
    expect(true).to be_true
  end

  context "do something afterwards" do
    after { puts "running something after test2!" }

    it "runs test2" do
      expect(5).not_to eq(4)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that, have a look [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/1200)

You can achieve that using `metadata` in rspec

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true
end

describe "Skip hook demo" do
  # If prior to RSpec 2.99.0.beta1
  after do
    puts "before hook" unless example.metadata[:skip]
  end

  # If RSpec 2.99.0.beta1 or later
  after do |example|
    puts "before hook" unless example.metadata[:skip]
  end

  it "will use before hook" do
  end

  it "will not use before hook", :skip do
  end
end
```